# Trigger a function in Google Sheets when a Google Form is edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-forms

I want to trigger a function in Google Sheets when a Google Form is edited. Specifically, I want a function to execute when a question in Google Forms is changed, deleted, added, or re-arranged. I can only figure out how to set up a trigger when a response is submitted.

Comment: Sounds like you want the Google Forms `onOpen` trigger. To paraphrase the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#open_3): "This event does occurs when an editor opens the form to modify it."